# How to turn an array of pixel data into a gif with node?

Tags: node.js, graphics

I'm trying to build a live gif, just for kicks, and I want to turn a 2D array of pixel data into a gif (or more specifically one frame of an animated gif).  I found [gifencoder](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gifencoder) and it works but it's slow as molasses (~800ms to encode a 500x500px gif).  Every other solution I can find (e.g. things built on graphicsmagick or imagemagick) don't seem to have a way to accept input streams, but just already encoded images.  I *suppose* I could just dump data to a `.bmp`, but that's a very roundabout way to accomplish this.  The other thing I'm thinking is just lzw encoding the data but before I go digging into the technical aspects of that I'm just fishing here for other ideas.

Comment: I am not sure this is relevant to your issue, but have you seen ImageMagick stream. See https://www.imagemagick.org/script/stream.php. Also you can read an RGB image with no header. See RGB at https://www.imagemagick.org/script/formats.php. Also  see https://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/files/#image_streams. I am not an expert on streams. I just wanted to be sure you have not overlooked these.

Comment: @fmw42 - thanks, that might actually work and was one consideration.  I didn't jump towards it because piping that much data through `stdout` tends to be pretty slow, but I can benchmark it to see.